# Similar module to splashify?

Tags: 7

I'm looking for alternative modules to create splash pages, similar to this: https://drupal.org/project/splashify

This is the only one I've found but I'm sure there should be more of this.

To make the search I used the "splash" keyword.

Does anyone know any other?

The idea is to popup a "colorbox" frame when the user log in, then the user would be able to check "I don't want to see this information anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [tinybox simple splash](https://drupal.org/project/tinybox)

> TinyBox module uses TinyBox, a lightweight and standalone modal window
>   script. The main purpose of this module is to provide Splash
>   Screen/Window as simple as possible.